# .MDF Database Client Software Requirement

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I have developed a program using C# Windows Forms and SQL Server 2014 `.mdf` database file. It's running well on my development machine. Now I want to install it on another PC without Visual Studio and SQL Server. What are the software requirements for the PC to run that program with `.mdf` database file? I don't want to install Visual Studio, SQL Server or any other tool on the client PC.

Comment: Unless you are connecting to a remote machine, it will need SQL server.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's a local db. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want to use a `.mdf` database file, you **MUST** install SQL Server - no way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2014 Express Localdb, that's what you'll need to install in the client machines. The msi can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 and is available in 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 1):

To use single mdf file, You can install **localDb** as described in [SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb)

To manage the localdb use  [SqlLocalDB Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility)

[Getting Start LocalDb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/)