# How to run a C# WinForms program with local database on another computer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created an application using Winforms and C#. To store various data of application, I use a database. In the application folder, I have a .mdf file called PricesDatabase.mdf.

I have added connection string to app.config:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PricesDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

My connection string looks like this:

```cs
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

I have used Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects to create MSI and exe files. Additionally, in Properties Prerequisites I have added SQL Server 2019 Express Local DB. After installation, I get error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
> Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
> log for error details.

How can I solve this connection error?

Comment: if you connect another PC DB in your sql IDE (SQLite Editor,sql management studio,etc )

Comment: Where did you try to store the database? You can't write to read-only folders like `Program Files` no matter what permissions you use. That was introduced in Windows 9x,  to prevent careless users from corrupting their own or other applications. It's well known and documented for the last 30 years that documents go into `My Documents` and application data in `ApplicationData`.  In Active Directory domains docs and data will even follow the user from machine to machine.  You can easily find the location of special folders like the roaming or local AppData folder

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224960/mdf-database-client-software-requirement